# Entity framework core 2.1 returning null list one-to-many relationship C#

Tags: c#, entity-framework, xamarin.forms, entity-framework-core

I try to use Entity Framework with code first having **Users** and **Roles** classes. **Roles** having fixed values which I'm seeding from **OnModelCreating**

```
public class Roles
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }  
    public Users Users {get;set;}
}

modelBuilder.Entity<Roles>().HasData(
                new Roles { Id = 1, Description = "Accountant" },
                new Roles { Id = 2, Description = "Marketing manager"},
                new Roles { Id = 3, Description = "Purchasing manager" },
                new Roles { Id = 4, Description = "Receptionist" },
```

On the other hand I'm having **Users** class

```
 public class Users
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Roles> Roles { get; set; } =
        new HashSet<Roles>();
    public string FName { get; set; }
    public string LName { get; set; }        
    public string Email { get; set; }        
}
```

and this is how I'm defining the relationship between them in my DBContext class

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<Users>()
                    .HasMany(pc => pc.Roles);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Roles>()
                    .HasOne<Users>().WithMany(x=>x.Roles);
```

Here's how I'm adding users object.

```
_dbContext.Users.Add(new Users{ FName = "firstName", LName= "LastNAme", Email= "email", Roles = {new Roles{Description="Accountant"}, new Roles{Description="Marketing manager"}} });

_dbContext.Users.Add(new Users{ FName = "firstName1", LName= "LastNAme1", Email= "email1", Roles = {new Roles{Description="Accountant"}, new Roles{Description="Marketing manager"}} });
```

I'm having another Class say **Office**

```
public class Office{
   public Users users{get; set;}
          }
```

Now, I'm saving **Office** object with newly created users object above (the two users object created above)

```
_dbContext.Office.Add(users1);
_dbContext.Office.Add(users2);
```

the problem here is when I'm getting the list of office, I'm getting 2 objects of offcie but in 1st object the users.roles list is null but the second object of office contains the users.roles which I saved. Same is happening if I'm saving 3 or 4 object, always last object is having the roles list but the other objects having null Roles.

```
var users = await _databaseContext.Office.Include(p => p.Users)
                                                        .Include(p=>p.Users.Roles)                         
                                                        .ToListAsync();
```

Is there anything else do I need to update my code ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where do you get `users1`/`users2` from and how can you add them to `_dbContext.Office`, which presumably is a `DbSet<Office>`?

Comment: There's a many-to-many relationship between Users and Roles. A user can have many roles and a role can be assigned to many users. Try creating the junction table in code first by configuring this way: modelBuilder.Entity<Users>().HasMany(r => r.Roles).WithMany(r => r.Users);

Comment: @dickrichie Thanks for the reply but I tried the same but no help.